# Issue with Jmeter Recording while opening data selection frames on Page form. Second frame on same page gets URL encoded and get a 404 from server

Tags: jmeter

I am facing an issue while recording with Jmeter using HTTP(s) Test Script Recorder. On this single page form, I click find/click scope icon to open a list of fields for selection. Once the selection frame is open, I can select a value or close it with or without selection. The issue is that when I start the recorder and open this single-page form for the first selection, the frame opens just fine no matter what selection field I choose on the form. During the same recording session, When I open the same or another field for selection I get a 404 from the server and the items in the frame do not display for selection.
In case, I stop the recording and start again, I can open one frame with items for selection, second time again the same issue is observed. I have tried redirect options on the recorder, Java, and HTTPclient4 but the issue is not resolved.

When I look at the recorded requests for the first selection (successful selection) I see the following requests.

First-time same frame - Get request

[image: first-time same frame - Get request]

First-time same frame - Get request

[image: first time same frame - next Get request]

First-time same frame - POST Request

[image: First time same frame - POST Request]

When I see the second request which failed with 404, I see the second time, URL encoding was selected on the get request and based on that second request have URL encoding like %2F characters. Also, the post request now has most of the parameters in the URL rather than as parameters.

Second-time same frame - First Get Request

[image: Second-time same frame - First Get Request]

Second-time same frame - Second Get Request

[image: Second time same frame - Second Get Request]

Second-time same frame - POST Request

[image: Second time same frame - POST Request]

If you observe the url here

> /xxxx/html/en/default/common/%2Fxxx-xxx%2Fhtml%2Fen%2Fdefault%2FreportTemplate%2FviewPageReport.jsp%3FpropertyId%3D208133&projectId=1&reportTemplId=151523&associatedId=206434273&selectType=single&smartField=1&manager=1&parentSOSubCategoryId=1&olv=1&tempSpecId=754388166098775919&bookmarkable=false

`/default/common/%2Fxxx-xxx%2Fhtml` on conversion becomes  `/default/common//xxx-xxx/html` so here we add an additional backslash as well. So this request is different that first frame POST request on the same recording and it creates a URL encoded request with an additional / thus causing a 404.

I am using Jmeter 5.1.1 and have tried older Jmeter versions as well but observe the same issue. I do not see the same issue with Loadrunner, Silk performer, fiddler or any other tool. I want to be able to record the second frame just like it records the first frame so that I do not do URL encoding for the following frames on a single form.

Answer (score 1):

In case of [GET](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET) request all the parameters are being added to the URL, and according to the [RFC 1738](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt) not all characters can be used in the URL, you can use only alphanumeric and `$-_.+!*'(),` others need to be [URL-encoded](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

If you do believe that JMeter builds the URL incorrectly you can raise an issue in [JMeter Bugzilla](https://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html), however be ready to provide a reproducible test script (it would be better for questions asked here as well).

In the meantime you can consider alternative ways of recording a JMeter test like [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium/)

Comment: Hi Dmitri, I am not able to export the .JMX from the recording using JMeter Chrome Extension. I just get the message - "Export to JMX failed." I did try to find why it is throwing the error but haven't being able to find anything yet.

Comment: You can try [saving HTTP requests into a HAR file](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/reference#save-as-har) from Chrome and then upload the file to the  [BlazeMeter Converter](https://converter.blazemeter.com/)